Storyboard exception in Runtime
I created the following Storyboard with Blend, if I run it in Blend it works. If I try to run it in Runtime I get the following exception
"The value of the 'Children' property in the path '(0).(1)[3].(2)' points to an immutable instance of 'System.Windows.Media.TransformCollection'."

Below is the XAML part
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Placeholder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="90"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="100"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="200"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Placeholder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="2"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

                <Border x:Name="Placeholder"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Style="{StaticResource NavPlaceholderStyle}">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>

This is in the code behind the Window
Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("Storyboard1");
storyboard.Begin();

I expected it to work

I solved the problem by removing the TransformGroup.Children by transforming the code like this:
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Placeholder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="100"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="200"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Placeholder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6000000" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>




<Border x:Name="Placeholder"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        Style="{StaticResource NavPlaceholderStyle}">
</Border>

and now the code no longer produces exceptions
